# Mac standard user and sudo command

Tags: mac, terminal

I just got a new MacBookPro. For safety concern, I created one admin user auser and a standard user suser. I am going to use the auser to do all the app installations and suer for normal use.

Something I do need to do some work in the root such as make a new folder in my HD from terminal. As in suser account, I tried this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /MyApps
```

I tried to type in password for auser the one for suser, neither seems working. I am not sure what supper user is referring to when a standard user is logged in. Is it root user? Or can a standard user run sudo command?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to promote yourself directly from a standard user to root unless you make some special preparations: edit /etc/sudoers as @Daniel Beck suggested, create a suid shell (*not* recommended), etc.  There is, however, a way to do it in two steps: use su to switch to your admin account, then sudo to switch to root:

```
su auser -c "sudo somecommand"
```

This'll ask for a password twice (unless you've used it in the last 5 minutes, then it'll only ask once); both times it wants the auser password (su always asks for the password of the account you're switching to, while sudo asks for the account you're switching from).  BTW, if you run this from a directory that auser does not have read permissions, you'll get an error message ("shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied"), but it will still work.

Comment: I was so focused on sudo, I totally forgot about su! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sudo visudo` from your admin account and add an entry for your regular user account to allow performing `sudo`.

`man sudoers` and `man visudo` will tell you how to do that exactly. In short:

Add a line like the following to allow your regular user with short name *shortname* to perform everything:

`shortname    ALL=(ALL) ALL`

You can restrict this to specific commands by replacing the last `ALL` to the names of programs allowed to run, e.g. `/bin/mkdir`.

Comment: I don't have my Mac to test it out right now. Do you mean that my auser is not in dudoers file in my case (new Mac)? By using this command I can add an admin user to sudoers?

Comment: No, not the admin, but rather the standard user. The admin is a sudoer by default.

Comment: @David Regular non-admin users are *not allowed* to use `sudo` — by default, only members of the *wheel* group (Administrator users) are allowed to use `sudo`. By doing what I suggest, you add that permission. That's why editing `/etc/sudoers` by invoking `visudo` needs to happen from your admin account auser.

Comment: Sounds not the right thing to do if I give the permission for the normal user with more power. Just accept the fact and do as admin if needed.

Comment: @David Consider using `su - auser` then, and entering that user's password. I'm not 100% certain, but I think this is possible even from regular user accounts. This'll open a login shell for the `auser` account, allowing you to run commands as `auser`.

Comment: @Daniel, I still don't understand why my standard user cannot run sudo, if an admin user is within sudoers by default.

Comment: @David Well, what difference do you expect to be btween regular and admin users, other than the ability to perform administrative tasks that require elevated privileges, which is what `sudo` is about?

Comment: @Daniel I guess you mean su -u auser?

Comment: @David No, I don't. It's the same as `su -l auser`. See `man su`. There's no `-u` argument to `su`.

Comment: @Daniel is su as same as sudo? I read Apple developer reference about sudo and found -u.

Comment: @David No it's not. Seriously, RTFM. `man sudo`. `man su`. It's not *that* much to read. One (`sudo`) requires you to have special permissions (i.e. being a *sudoer*) and to enter your own password, or not, depending on configuration. The other (`su`) logs you into another user account, requiring *that other user's* credentials. Which is what I wrote several comments ago. Just try to use it and see for yourself. You can't break stuff if you restrict yourself to commands like `whoami` and `id` afterwards.